# factory_girl vs fixtures for development data (Rails)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, testing, factory-bot, fixtures

I like the factory_girl approach in tests, but one thing I'm a little unclear on is what to do about development data.

Usually with fixtures we had some dummy users, models etc in development.  Then in tests we can create more on the fly or reference the existing ones but every developer had the same data in dev.

What's the common way to create development data with factory_girl?  I saw rake db:seed but this looks like it's intended to be used in production also, so not quite the same thing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I generally create fake data using Factories inside `seeds.rb`.

I just prepend the code with `if Rails.env.development?`